# AAD CallbackUrl generated is an IP address and does not match reply Url in app registration when deployed to service fabric

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-service-fabric

I'm setting up authentication using Azure Active Directory with an ASP.NET Core 2.2 web app service that is deployed to azure service fabric. I set it up using the template in visual studio and it works well when deployed locally. When I deployed it to azure however, I get the "AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application" error and i noticed in the URL it lists the generated redirect URI as https://IP.ADDRESS:PORT#/signin-oidc. If I add this ip address in my app registration it wont give me the error but redirecting me to that address doesn't actually take me anywhere. What can I do to fix this?

I thought it might be some reverse proxy issue and I tried some fixes to try and give me an absolute path to my service on the cluster eg: https://mycluster.azure-api.net/myapplication/myservice/signin-oidc but none of these worked

Also the CallbackPath property needs to start with a "/" so I can't just add the full address there either, it throws an error.

Some of my code in the startup.cs, a lot of this was auto-generated:

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => BindAad(options))
                .AddCookie();

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        private void BindAad(AzureADOptions options)
        {
            options.Instance = settings.GetSetting("AadInstance");
            options.Domain = settings.GetSetting("AadDomain");
            options.TenantId = settings.GetSetting("AadTenantId");
            options.ClientId = settings.GetSetting("AadClientId");
            options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oidc");
        }



       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
            });
        }
```

Comment: Did you see this walkthrough on how to configure openid connect for aspnet core? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg

Answer (score 1):

The link LoekD supplied should be useful to you.

You just need to have the reply URL in your code matching what you have in your app registration. If it works locally but does not work with your published application then that means that you still have references to the local url somewhere. You need to use your published application URL in both the code and in the portal (myapp.azurewebsites.net).

Comment: That link does not help actually. I am facing the same issue. Problem is that it is picking up kubernetes ip instead of DNS name.